# Excel Import Into Access

Tags: sql, database, excel, ms-access

I have 3 spreadsheets that I want to import into Access but I"m having a problem figuring it out. I'm not even sure it can be done the way I want to do it.

One Spreadsheet looks like this:

```
StoreNum, SKU_1, SKU_2, SKU_3, ..., SKU_1000  
1, 0, 100, 25, ..., 1  
2, 5, 250, 15, ..., 5  
3, 78, 25, 12, ..., 15
```

How can I import this so I have StoreNum, SKU, Qty?

The others are easy for me to understand

```
StoreNum, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip
```

and

```
Sku, Description, Notes, Size
```

Comment: the reason you have not gotten this answered is because your question is confusing. what don't you understand about how to import into access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to store the spreadsheet data in Access like this ...

```
StoreNum  SKU Qty
       1    1   0
       1    2 100
       1    3  25
       1 1000   1
       2    1   5
```

If that's what you want, keep reading.  If it's not what you want, please clarify what you want.

In Access, create a link to the Excel worksheet and name that link `ExcelSource`.

Then create a `SELECT` query similar to this:

```
SELECT
    StoreNum,
    1 AS SKU,
    SKU_1 AS Qty
FROM ExcelSource
UNION ALL
SELECT
    StoreNum,
    2 AS SKU,
    SKU_2 AS Qty
FROM ExcelSource
UNION ALL
SELECT
    StoreNum,
    3 AS SKU,
    SKU_3 AS Qty
FROM ExcelSource
UNION ALL
SELECT
    StoreNum,
    1000 AS SKU,
    SKU_1000 AS Qty
FROM ExcelSource;
```

If the result set from that `SELECT` query gives you what you need, convert it to an "append query" to store those data in a table named `YourTable`.  The SQL for that query will be the `SELECT` SQL preceded by an `INSERT INTO ...` section:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (StoreNum, SKU, Qty)
SELECT
    StoreNum,
    1 AS SKU,
    SKU_1 AS Qty
FROM ExcelSource
UNION ALL
SELECT
    StoreNum,
    2 AS SKU,
    SKU_2 AS Qty
FROM ExcelSource
UNION ALL
SELECT
    StoreNum,
    3 AS SKU,
    SKU_3 AS Qty
FROM ExcelSource
UNION ALL
SELECT
    StoreNum,
    1000 AS SKU,
    SKU_1000 AS Qty
FROM ExcelSource;
```

If your Excel worksheet includes 1000 SKU columns, create a series of smaller append queries, each of which uses a manageable subset of those 1000 columns.

This could also be done with VBA code rather than a query.  I don't want to lead you through that option because I don't even know if I'm on the right track here.

Answer (score 0):

When you open your Access database click;

> File
>
> > Get External Data
> >
> > > Import

And follow the Wizard Steps.

A few caution points.  Make sure that all of your excel sheets have the same headers, and do not contain any Null, DIV, or any other type of errors.  Happy importing!!!